# GCP Cloud Function to create VM instance does not recognise my custom image

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a Cloud Function in Python that builds a VM instance using a custom image I previously created.

The source image is present in the images section:

[image]

However, when i run the Cloud Function it can't find my image to build the instance and returns the following error:

```
Details: "Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'projects/<<project id>>/global/images/pandora-pagespeed-image'. The referenced image resource cannot be found.">
```

What is more, if I go to create a VM instance manually in the console the image is not appearing here either:

[image]

Stranger still, the image that *is* appearing (pandora-image) is an old image that was deleted yesterday.

What might be going on here?

My Cloud Function code is:

```
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
sa_file = <<credentials file>>
zone = 'europe-west2-c'
project_id = <<project id>> # Project ID, not Project Name

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(sa_file, scopes=scopes)

# Create the Cloud Compute Engine service object
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

def create_instance(compute, project, zone, name):
    # Get the latest Debian Jessie image.
    image_response = (
        compute.images()
        .getFromFamily(project="debian-cloud", family="debian-9")
        .execute()
    )
    source_disk_image = image_response["selfLink"]

    # Configure the machine
    machine_type = "zones/%s/machineTypes/n1-standard-1" % zone
    config = {
        "name": name,
        "machineType": machine_type,
        # Specify the boot disk and the image to use as a source.
        "disks": [
            {
                "kind": "compute#attachedDisk",
                "type": "PERSISTENT",
                "boot": True,
                "mode": "READ_WRITE",
                "autoDelete": True,
                "deviceName": "instance-1",
                "initializeParams": {
                    "sourceImage": "projects/<<project id>>/global/images/pandora-pagespeed-image",
                    "diskType": "projects/<<project id>>/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-standard",
                    "diskSizeGb": "10",
                },
                "diskEncryptionKey": {},
            }
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "kind": "compute#metadata",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "startup-script",
        "value": "sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip\npip3 install -r /home/tommyp/pandora/requirements.txt\ncd /home/tommyp/pandora\npython3 /home/tommyp/pandora/main.py"
      }
    ]
        },
        "networkInterfaces": [
            {
                "network": "global/networks/default",
                "accessConfigs": [{"type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT", "name": "External NAT"}],
            }
        ],
        "tags": {"items": ["http-server", "https-server"]},
    }

    return compute.instances().insert(project=project, zone=zone, body=config).execute()

def run(data, context):
    create_instance(service, project_id, zone, "vm-instance")
```

Comment: Is your first screenshot is a Image or Snapshot screenshot?

Comment: It’s a screenshot of the Images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized now what I did wrong.

I created my image in the '[machine images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images)' section, not the 'images' section. Hence why my image could not be found...DOH!